# How to see how many column(a) values are for each column(b) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Column(a) is a Id field. Now column(b) can have many column(a)s attached to one column(b). How can i write this query so i can return for example

```
column(b) | Total column(a)s
```

It would be something like the following:

```
Select [DCN-field], COUNT(woid) FROM wo
ORDER BY COUNT(DCN-field) DESC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [DCN-field], COUNT(woid) FROM wo
    GROUP BY [DCN-field]
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Try it out and let us know if it works for you.

For any further clarifications please don't hesitate to contact me again.

Ted.